# $A$ is complex matrix and $A^3=A$. Show that $rk(A)=tr(A^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is complex matrix and $A^3=A$. Show that $rk(A)=tr(A^2)$

I'm more concerned with how I can derive the prove of this question. before I ask this question, I fail to prove that whit jordan canonical form

Comment: The matrix equality is equivalent to $A^2(A) = A$. What does this mean about the columns of $A$ relative to $A^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A^3=A$ then we have

- $A^3-A = A(A^2-I)= A(A-I)(A+I)=0 \rightarrow$ the eigenvalues of $A$ can only be $0,1,-1$
- $rk(A) =rk(A^3) \leq rk(A^2) \leq rk(A) \rightarrow rk(A) = rk(A^2)$
- the eigenvalues of $A^2$ can only be $0,1$ and $tr(A^2)= rk(A^2)$ is the (algebraic) multiplicity of the eigenvalue 1. (think of the Jordan form of $A$ and $A^2$)
- $\rightarrow rk(A) = tr(A^2)$

Comment: how does the jordan form work to prove $tr(A^2)=rk(A^2)$ ?

Comment: And from equation $A^3-A=0$ that is not the polynomial characteristic. So we can not claim all of 0,1,-1 must be eigenvalue of $A$, right?

Comment: @lio we can say, that $A$ can only have these eigenvalues. Of course $A =0$ would also satisfy the given condition. The main point is, that $A^2$ has as many 1's as it's rank. Thanks for this hint. I edited correspondingly and made it more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A^3-A=0$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(t-1)(t+1)t$. Hence the minimal polynomial can be factorized in distinct linear factors. This implies that all Jordan blocks of $A$ have size $1$, hence $A$ is diagonalizable.

The rank of $A$ is the number of non-zero eigenvalues of $A$, which is equal to the number of non-zero eigenvalues of $A^2$ by diagonalizability, which is equal to $tr(A^2)$ as the only non-zero eigenvalue of $A^2$ is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A^3 - A = 0$, it follows that $p(A) =0$, with $p(t) = t^3 - t = t(t+1)(t-1)$.

It is well-known that the *minimal polynomial* $\varphi(t)$ of $A$, which is the unique monic polynomial of minimal degree that annihilates $A$, must divide every polynomial that annihilates $A$. Thus, if $p(A) = 0$ and $\varphi$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, then there is a polynomial $\psi$ such that $p = \varphi \psi$.

In the example above, this leaves the following possibilities:
\begin{align}
\varphi(t) &= t \\
\varphi(t) &= t+1 \\
\varphi(t) &= t- 1 \\
\varphi(t) &= t(t+1) \\
\varphi(t) &= t(t-1) \\
\varphi(t) &= (t+1)(t-1) \\
\varphi(t) &= t(t+1)(t-1).
\end{align}

One can examine each case individually. For instance, if $\varphi(t) = t(t+1)(t-1)$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1 = 1$ with multiplicity $m_1 \ge 1$; $\lambda_2 = -1$ with multiplicity $m_2 \ge 1$; and $\lambda_3 = 1$ with multiplicity $m_3 \ge 1$. In this case, $\text{rank}(A) = m_1 + m_2$ and since the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $\lambda_1$, with multiplicity $m_1+m_2$, and $\lambda_3$, with multiplicity $m_3$, it follows that $\text{tr}(A^2) = m_1 + m_2$ (see observations below).

> **Observation 1**. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v$, then $A^nv=\lambda^n v$ for every positive integer $n.$
>
> **Observation 2**. If $A$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ (multiplicities included), then $\text{tr}(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_1$.

Comment: why the $rk(A)=m_1 + m_2$ ? is that only when $A$ diagonalizable or generally always like that?

Comment: The rank of a matrix equals the number of nonzero eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: So all nilpotent matrix is zero ?